# Nservicebus - Temporarily suspend endpoint

Tags: nservicebus, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am using Nservicebus 4.7.5 with azure service bus as transport. My endpoint is just a subscriber of events and it doesn't publish anything. My endpoint once it receives an event calls into a azure storage and performs a CRUD.

Now when the azure storage datacenter is offline temporarily, the endpoint would continue to run and the messages would go into dead letter queue.

I am looking for a way to stop my endpoint consuming messages when there is an temporary issue in my storage adlnd therefore prevent them from going into dead letter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought that ASB will discard old messages and you will not have any messages at all? At least now you have them in the error queue. It is **much** better to count for a rare exception and have a way to address it when it happens, instead of building a workaround.

Imagine that I have a power outage in my office and it happens like once in six months. I would not start building a diesel generator facility because of this. Instead, I would develop some plan how to handle these outages using what I already have.

What you can do if you want to stop processing completely, is to implement a [circuit breaker](http://particular.net/blog/protect-your-software-with-the-circuit-breaker-design-pattern). NServiceBus uses it when the transport goes down. If a blob storage is equally important component for your service, you can use it too. It will stop the service completely after some retries (unless you develop your own version).

Comment: To add to what @Alexey said, you can also configure your SLR to be extended. With SLR set to 30 mins, and 3 attempts, you'll have retries after 30, 60, 90 minutes. This can also help with an outage scenario.